# Avoiding use of global variables with specific callback mechanism in Lua

Tags: lua, callback

I want to use a Lua API which has specific callback functions when events occur, e.g. when an TCP package arrives. At first the function have to be registered but by the functions name as a string, see the sample code below

```
function __init__()
    local dstport = 4681
    local dstIP = "192.168.1.42"
    -- register the callback function 
    register_tcp_handler('tcp_package_handler', dstIP, dstPort)
end

-- callback function
function tcp_package_handler(srcIP, srcPort, dstIP, dstPort, payload)
    -- check the payload, or reset watchdog
end
```

It would be nice to have other variables in callback function provided by the callee, e.g. watchdog-timer or other objects.

The most simple way I could think of is to make the extravariables global, but it is the least elegant way I reckon. Closures would be helpful if I could pass the function directly, but i can not. I have to use the functions name as a string.

Considering this mechanics, is there a more elegant way to privide variables to the callback function without making them global?

EDIT: Using closures like this

```
function closure_tcp_package_handler(srcIP, srcPort, dstIP, dstPort, payload, packagecounter, timerobject)
    function tcp_package_handler(srcIP, srcPort, dstIP, dstPort, payload)
        -- do some stuff, change packagecounter, timerobject
    end
    return 'tcp_package_handler'
end
```

and use this function twice to register, e.g. with `packagecounter1, timerobject1` and `packagecounter2, timerobject2`, only the last pair of parameters will be changed.

Comment: You can make a closure, assign in to global variable `tcp_package_handler` and pass it to `register_tcp_handler`

Comment: @Daniel: Are these "variables/parameters" constant throughout the execution of your program? Or do you need to change their values? Because if they're fixed, I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @NicolBolas I defnitely need to change their values.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I edited my question with an example what I tried, does this match to the meaning of your comment? If not can you elaborate more with sample code preferably?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of your usage with different variable values?  What scope will they be modified from?

Comment: @DanielR. - How are you going to attach two closures to the same event? You could only detach the first closure and attach the second.  Actually, you need only one closure to do all the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with a callback infrastructure. In which case, your code is not the one invoking the handler. As such, there's no way to hide those parameters; if you can change them, so can someone else with access to the module providing the handler.

That doesn't mean that they have to be global, of course. You could make them members of a table. You could even provide setter functions to set the parameters, if you want to make sure that they only get certain parameters.

The simple form of this is as follows:

```
local handler_params = {}

function tcp_package_handler(srcIP, srcPort, dstIP, dstPort)
    -- check `handler_params.payload`
end

--Make `handler_params` available for outside modification
```

How you do that last part is entirely up to you. You could have made it a global, but if this is in a module somewhere, it'd be better to make it a member of that module's table. And again, if you want to have some control over who gets to poke at it and how, you can use setter functions:

```
function tcp_handler_set_payload(payload)
  handler_params.payload = payload
end
```